# Make iPhone hotspot always detectable on Android phone

Tags: iphone, wifi, tethering, android

Is there any method to make an iPhone hotspot always detectable on an Android phone? It is really inconvenient that despite the hotspot switch always being on it is still necessary for the iPhone to go to the hotspot screen each time I connect the Android phone. I understand that for Apple devices family sharing could help to make the hotspot always detectable but that this does not work for Android devices. Is there any setting or app that would keep the hotspot detectable all the time?

Comment: No.  If you made the phone beacon all the time, everyone would just complain about the battery.  Apple devices know the hotspot is there, because they're all logged into the same Apple ID, and use BTLE to ask the iOS device to actually turn the hotspot on.

Comment: Note that every other phone brand works perfectly fine with the "beacon" being on for long times. Seems more like Apple using horrible (evil) protectionistic designs to force you to use apple for everything. As usual.